# preventing uninstallation of c++ redistributable

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I'm using [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) in my product. as part of the installation, the installer installs c++ redistributables that my product needs in order to run. my question is how to prevent the user from removing the c++ redistributable installation in add/remove programs? is there an option to use reference counting on 3rd party products that the installer installs?

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered [using merge modules to install your redistributables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235290%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)? Instead of separate standalone installers. This is supported by Advanced Installer too.

This should prevent them from appearing in Control Panel, but they will also be uninstalled together with your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the user from removing the redistributable installation from Add/Remove programs, please see the MSDN documentation: [Configuring Add/Remove Programs with Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/2eb00fe5-e441-4fce-9623-81a089269a2b). You could use the [ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/fa3510b4-c4de-4261-ae6c-4292b88432ef) to prevent the redistributable from being displayed in the Add or Remove Programs list of Control Panel. This should hide the redistributable installation, but you can still use the Windows Installer to install, uninstall, repair, and reinstall the application. If the user uninstalls your application, it should be designed to also uninstall the redistributable. The recommended alternative to using concurrent installations is to instead use a setup application and external UI handler to install several Windows Installer packages sequentially.

Note however that [Microsoft recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/ff48d995-fe6f-4d1b-898d-67574ed3c5b7#concurrent_installs) that no one use [concurrent installations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/579ae4ee-47a0-440e-81ca-ea8bf60c5349) to install or update a shipping product. A concurrent installation action installs another Windows Installer package during a currently running installation.